# Passing a component a navigation screen via props from screen component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I am building an app that has a list on the home screen routing to a number of other screens.

I created a list component that is rendered on the home page, and therefore, need to pass the navigation down to the list component. The list component, in turn, will determine which screen to display depending on which item is pressed.

I am using a `Stack Navigator` on my **router.js** file

```
export const HomeStack = StackNavigator({

Home: {
  screen: Home,
  navigationOptions: {
    title: 'Home',
  },
},
Nutrition: {
   screen: Nutrition,
   navigationOptions: {
     title: 'Nutrition',
    }
  },
});
```

In my **home.js** screen I have the below code inside the render method

```
render() {
 return (
  <View>
      <View>
        <ListComponent navigate={this.props.navigation.navigate('')} />
        <Button
        title="Go to Nutrition"
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Nutrition')}
        />
      </View>
  </View>
);
```

}

The Button successfully routes to the **Nutrition.js** screen.

But, I try to get my **ListComponent.js** to handle where to route as this file maps through my list array.

```
  render() {
   return (
     <List>
       {ListData.map((listItem, i) => (
        <ListItem
        key={i}
        title={listItem.title}
        leftIcon={{ name: listItem.icon }}
        onPress={this.onPressHandler(listItem.title)}
        />
      ))}
     </List>
   );
 }
```

How can I properly pass the navigation as props down to **ListComponent.js** and then use the title from the list array to determine which screen to display?

Comment: in the array add the screen names and pass in the ListView

Comment: how would I pass the ListView into the array?

Comment: pass array into the listview not ListView into array

Comment: @ParasWatts I'm already passing my array into the list view when I map over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line :

```
   <ListComponent navigate={this.props.navigation.navigate('')} />
```

to this :

```
   <ListComponent navigate={(screen)=>this.props.navigation.navigate(screen)}/>
```

and change this

```
  <ListItem
    key={i}
    title={listItem.title}
    leftIcon={{ name: listItem.icon }}
    onPress={this.onPressHandler(listItem.title)}
    />
```

to this :-

```
  <ListItem
    key={i}
    title={listItem.title}
    leftIcon={{ name: listItem.icon }}
    onPress={()=>this.props.navigate(listItem.title)}
    />
```

As you are calling the method directly not binding it to the component.

I am assuming that your code in ListItem.js is correct.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the list component's onPress property to route to each screen?

Comment: check updated code, if this not works please explain your question more clearly and add more code files.